# Which option should I choose while Installing Ubuntu 12.04 along with Windows 7 x64?

Tags: system-installation

This image shows the options that I can choose. Which should be the best and minimal to install Ubuntu 12.04 along with Windows 7 x64. If you can explain things using screen-shots it will be better.

[image]

I do not want to set anything manually. Choosing which option can make Ubuntu 12.04 automatically set the bootloader settings for Windows and Ubuntu itself ?

Here is a another question that shows the screen-shots of my hdd allocation tables:
[Can I install Ubuntu on a logical partition ? What will be the advantage or disadvantage of using a logical partition to install Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136035/can-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-logical-partition-what-will-be-the-advantage-or-disa)

Comment: I have also added info to your other question. Please remember to accept an answer by clicking on the "Accept Check" logo and/or upvoting the answer. That way we know you accepted an answer and got the help you needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should select the first option. The first option would actually say "Install Ubuntu alongside Microsoft Windows 7" but it looks like you have several Operation Systems installed there. Select the first one and from there on you can choose the size for the partition space for Ubuntu.

Also all options can set Ubuntu to automatically set the bootloader as you mention but for your the easiest would be, again, the first one.

From the link you have provided, you can install Ubuntu on that logical 55GB space you have left.

Comment: Ok thanks. Does going with the first option automatically creates the Swap Partition ?

Comment: Yes. It is pretty straight forward. It does everything for you. Your only problem now would be selecting your username and password ^^.

Comment: No Curious it was a joke. I was kidding. It is very easy. Just click the first option and Ubuntu setup will guide you step by step. It is by far the easiest way to install any system. You won't have any problems. Sorry for the bad joke.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the first option as it is easy and will give no headaches to you. Upon completing the installation and reboot, select windows to run and do the repair if any is needed.Then come back to Ubuntu and enjoy it.

Comment: What kinda repair I might have to make ?

Comment: @CuriousApprentice: Since the first option resizes your Windows partition, it is recommended to run `chkdsk` when you get back to Windows after installation of Ubuntu to ensure the Filesystem remains "healthy". Also in worst cases, resizing a fragmented Windows partition may lead to corrupt filesystem or unbootable Windows (which is very unlikely to happen). So "repairs" here suggests to run `chkdsk`. Also, it is highly recommended to de-fragment Windows partition before you proceed to install Ubuntu using this method.