# Can I install Ubuntu on logical partition under an extended partition while triple booting windows, Ubuntu and Kali Linux?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, boot-partition, boot-order

I am triple booting windows 10, Ubuntu and Kali Linux. So is it possible to install Ubuntu and Kali Linux on logical partitions under extended partitions or will it not work without primary partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can!
See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/136064/526457) answer for details.

Also, consider using a GPT disk, since all of your operating systems seem to support it!

Comment: My lenovo g50-80 doesn't seem to like UEFI much. Even when there's a option in BIOS settings it always fails to boot any OS. So GPT is out of question. Btw should I make different partitions for /boot, /, /var, etc. Or should I install everything in single partition?

Comment: I always use a single partition mounted as "/" and another one for swap. I haven't faced any problems. But try looking for [this](http://superuser.com/a/66022/585778) answer.

Comment: Have you ever upgraded your Linux from within instead of doing clean install everytime a new version comes out? Last time when I upgraded Ubuntu when I was dual booting with Windows, Windows crashed and I had to format everything. Anyways thanks for helping, I'll put swap at the start of the disk followed by primary for Windows and then extended for both Linux and then an ntfs or fat32 extended for my personal files at the end.

Comment: Never. Because I'm afraid it leads to lots of bugs. I always backup everything, write all actively used apps and package names into a text file, do a clean install, restore necessary files and reinstall apps.

Comment: You're welcome! Putting swap at the start is a great idea to speed it up. I always do that. I would recommend ntfs as it supports files > 4 GB in size and is supported by Linux pretty well.